# Building Android APK with Ant ignores signing password

Tags: android, ant, apk

I've noticed that when using ant to build and sign an apk file, the password for the key store is ignored. I am prompted twice for a password, once for the keystore:

```
-release-prompt-for-password:
```

and once for my alias:

```
[input] Please enter password for alias 'myAlias':
```

It is the alias password which is ignored. I can enter anything without being informed of an error and ant reports that the build was successful. I can successfully install the resulting apk.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance...

Comment: Maybe the alias password was not set? I doubt its possible to create such a keystore without password for alias, but that would be my first guess.

Comment: @inazaruk Can't be that as when I export via eclipse, it notices when the password is incorrect

Comment: You can create keystore from command line as well. Did you create keystore yourself? Or was it created by someone else?

Comment: @inazaruk I did create the keystore. The problem is solved - see below. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've solved the problem - the keystore password and alias password were identical. This seemed to allow the signing process using ant to pass when entering the wrong password for the alias.

If I make the passwords differ, the build process does indeed fail if the wrong alias password is entered.